# Why is type Type[] not assignable to property of type Type[]?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vuejs3, primevue

Setup:

- OS: Windows 11 with Ubuntu WSL2
- Editor: VSCode with "Vue Language Features (Volar)" extension
- Language: TypeScript
- Framework: Vue3
- Components: Primevue

The code works as intended, but VSCode seems to think there's a mistake (see comment in code below)::

```js
const props = withDefaults(defineProps<{
    hasHeader: boolean;
    isCloseable: boolean;
    isVisible: boolean;
    headerTitle?: string;
    menuItems: MenuItem[];
}>(), {
    hasHeader: true,
    isCloseable: false,
    isVisible: true,
    headerTitle: "Insurances",
    menuItems: [ // <-- "menuItems" is squigly-underlined in red
        {
            label: "Offers",
            to: "/offers",
        },
        {
            label: "Representatives",
            to: "/representatives",
            items: [
                {
                    label: "Mentorship",
                    to: "/representatives/mentorship",
                },
            ],
        },
        {
            label: "Customers",
            to: "/customers",
        },
    ] as MenuItem[],
});
```

This is the error message when I hover the `menuItems`.

```
(property) menuItems?: ((props: Readonly<{
    hasHeader: boolean;
    isCloseable: boolean;
    isVisible: boolean;
    headerTitle?: string | undefined;
    menuItems: MenuItem[];
}>) => MenuItem[]) | undefined
Type 'MenuItem[]' is not assignable to type '(props: Readonly<{ hasHeader: boolean; isCloseable: boolean; isVisible: boolean; headerTitle?: string | undefined; menuItems: MenuItem[]; }>) => MenuItem[]'.
  Type 'MenuItem[]' provides no match for the signature '(props: Readonly<{ hasHeader: boolean; isCloseable: boolean; isVisible: boolean; headerTitle?: string | undefined; menuItems: MenuItem[]; }>): MenuItem[]'.ts(2322)
Sidebar.vue(108, 2): The expected type comes from property 'menuItems' which is declared here on type 'InferDefaults<Readonly<{ hasHeader: boolean; isCloseable: boolean; isVisible: boolean; headerTitle?: string | undefined; menuItems: MenuItem[]; }>>'
```

I've tried all four combinations of adding or removing `as MenuItem` for each item in the list and adding or removing `as MenuItem[]` for the list itself.

Anyone understands the error?

Answer (score 0):

Object or array defaults must be returned from a factory function. Factory functions guarantee that a new object is created for each component instance, meaning a mutation in one instance won't affect the prop value in a different instance (this problem is not possible with primitive values, hence why it's only needed for Objects/Arrays).

Declare your `menuItems` default value like this:

```js
menuItems: () => [ ... ] as MenuItem[]
```